# How do I get 'open with vs code' option in MacBook?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, open-with

[image: getting the option in individual .py files]
[image: not getting it for the folders]

I tried it various times by reinstalling it but there is no option as 'open with vs code' after installing it.

Comment: What exactly are you asking about? You give no explanation of what the screenshots are showing. The first one shows that such a menu option exists for files. The second shows that there is no "Open With" entry for folders. Are you asking specifically about opening folders?

Answer (score 0):

That's Finder (the "Windows Explorer" there) for macOS, which does not have such a feature.